# Recurring message in the Function app Log stream, where does it come from?

Tags: azure-functions

My .net 7 function app is running fine, but a message frequently occur in the Log stream, and I don't understand where it is coming from. None of my code is using "Azure.Strorage.Blogs". Any ideas?

This is the message:

> Headers: Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
> x-ms-request-id: 81b71c3a-c01e-0003-2cc1-859e40000000 x-ms-error-code:
> OutOfRangeInput Date: Sat, 13 May 2023 17:39:01 GMT .
>
> 2023-05-13T17:39:06Z [Verbose] Host instance '....' failed to acquire
> host lock lease: Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed. Status:
> 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.) ErrorCode:
> OutOfRangeInput

Answer (score 1):

This log is from an internal implementation of the functions runtime. Unless you see your functions being affected, you can ignore this.

Some triggers like the Timer trigger for example uses this kind of blob storage lease as a distributed lock to ensure only one function app instance is being executed.